# How do i map this in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I Have two classes, Survey and Poll classes. Also I have Question and Question Choice classes. How do I map these so I come out with particular table formats. Here are the classes involved.

```
public class Survey
{
     public IList<Question> Questions { get; private set; }   
}

public class Poll
{
    public Question Question { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public IList<QuestionChocie> Choices { get; private set; }
}

public class QuestionChoice
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The resulting tables that I'm shooting for include the following

```
Surveys- a table of survey information.
Polls - a table of polls information.
SurveyQuestions -a table of survey questions.
PollQuestions - a table of poll questions.
SurveyChoices - a table of the question choices for the surveys.
PollChoices - a table of the question choices for the survey.
```

Preferably, I really want to know for Fluent NHibernate, or just mapping xml is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined relationships between the tables so I'm going to assume one-to-many.

The general mapping would be:

```
public class SurveyMap : ClassMap<Survey>
{
    public SurveyMap()
    {
        HasMany<SurveyQuestion>(x => x.Questions).Inverse();
        // Rest of mapping
    }
}

public class SurveyQuestionMap : ClassMap<Question>
{
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        References<Survey>(x => x.Survey);
        HasMany<SurveyChoice>(x => x.Choices).Inverse();
        // Rest of mapping
    }
}

public class SurveyChoiceMap : ClassMap<SurveyChoice>
{
    public SurveyChoiceMap()
    {
        References<SurveyQuestion>(x => x.Question);
        // Rest of mapping
    }
}
```

Comment: Stuart, I think you can drop the type names between <...>. They should be inferred unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You're right, you can leave the types off. It's just my preference to leave it in so that it's clear what I'm mapping. I like to read it as "Has many X through Y" or "References X through Z."